# Azure Function: blobs_extension app key keeps changing

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

How can I keep the blobs_extension app key persistent so that I don't have to update the Webhook event subscription endpoint every time I restart or re-deploy a function or change any function or blob storage account settings? The app key keeps changing in an Azure Function that I am working on based on the workflow described in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-java#get-the-blob-extension-key), causing the function to stop processing data. Thank you!

That mostly happens when function is stopped and restarted. For the re-deployments it mostly remains the same, so I see function running

```java
    @FunctionName("BlobFunction")
    public void run(@BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "%MY_PATH%", dataType = "string", connection = "StorageString", source = "EventGrid") String content,
                    @BindingName("name") String name,
                    @KafkaOutput(name = "kafkaOutput", topic = "%TOPIC%", brokerList = "%BROKER_LIST%",
                            username = "$ConnectionString",
                            password = "EventHubConnection",
                            authenticationMode = BrokerAuthenticationMode.PLAIN,
                            protocol = BrokerProtocol.SASLSSL) OutputBinding<KafkaEntity> output,
                    final ExecutionContext context) {

        final KafkaEntity kafkaMessage = new KafkaEntity(0, 0, System.getenv("TOPIC"),
                Instant.now().toString(), content, customer, new KafkaHeaders[]{new KafkaHeaders("name", name)});

        output.setValue(kafkaMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: Added code to the question

Answer (score 0):

The system keys are, by default, persisted through the AzureWebJobsStorage connection. If something changes there such that the system no longer sees a value to use, it will create a new one using whatever storage is available to it. But if nothing has changed for that specific connection, then we would expect no unprompted rotation to occur for a system key. In particular, an explicit stop/restart on its own is not expected to make any changes to the system state.

Can you clarify what this means? “change any function or blob storage account settings”